# What is the purpose of /*+ */ in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Why do we use `/* */` on sql?
For example:

```
select /*+ index(sssi_iq SITE_STAT_TSTAMP_IDX) */
```

Can anyone explain, please?

Comment: It's a way of commenting sql

Comment: -- comments out a single line

Comment: /* start of comment

comments out lots of lines

end of comments */

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF00219

Comment: see also some [stackoverflow docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1490/hints#t=201611220739046861188)

Comment: /* use for commenting. anyway This is not tutorial site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are Oracle Optimizer hint which directs the optimizer to perform the task as per our requirements.

`/*+ hint [text] [hint[text]]... */`

For more: [Optimizer Hints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/hintsref.htm#i8327)

Answer (score 8):

`--` is a line comment, e.g. -

```
select      * 
from        t -- this is a line comment
order by    i
```

`/* */` is a multi-line comment, e.g. -

```
select      * 
from        t /* this is 
   a multi-line line 
      comment */
order by  /* and so is this */  i
```

When `+` is added (`/*+ */` or `--+`) it is an indication to an **optimizer hint**, Which is an instruction to the optimizer that the optimizer **might or might not** respect.
In oracle you get no indication (error/warring) if your hint is being ignored.

Example:

```
create table t1 (i int);
create table t2 (i int);
```

---

#### Accepted Hints

```
select /*+ use_nl    (t1,t2) */ * from t1 join t2 on t1.i = t2.i;
```

[image]

```
select /*+ use_merge (t1,t2) */ * from t1 join t2 on t1.i = t2.i;
```

[image]

```
select /*+ use_hash  (t1,t2) */ * from t1 join t2 on t1.i = t2.i;
```

[image]

#### Ignored Hints

```
select /*+ use_hash  (t1,t2) */ * from t1 join t2 on t1.i != t2.i;
```

[image]

```
select /*+ use_merge (t1,t2) */ * from t1 join t2 on t1.i != t2.i;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

it just comment block,
multi-line comment /* comment goes here*/
single line --comment goes here 
other formats for comments in oracle is double hyphen.
for example

```
 -- this is a query about date 
/* this is
a query
about
date */
select sysdate from dual;
```